# How to show Typescript Type Alias relationships in an IDEA plugin - best idea so far: via Program Structure Interface - aka: intellij psi

Tags: typescript, intellij-plugin, type-alias

**TLDR; Is there an API to manage TypeScript Type Alias relationships in the Intellij Plugin framework?**

I am trying to extend this lovely IDEA plugin: https://github.com/vepanimas/intellij-uml-javascript to support Typescript Type Aliases. At present, it will show Types, but not their relationships.

ie:

```
type A = {};
type B = {};
type C = {};
type D = {};

type AB = A & B;
type CD = C & D;
type ABorCD = AB | CD;

type A1 = A & {};
type A2 = A1 & {};
```

Looks like this:
[diagramFromPlugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7d9.png)
And for those of you who don't feel like clicking the link, it's just a bunch of unconnected boxes. No relationships exist at all.

---

My first problem is that I'm trying to create an overloaded processParents() method with TypeScriptType like so:

```
private static void processParents(@NotNull TypeScriptType element, @NotNull Processor<TypeScriptType> processor) {
    processParents(element, processor, TypeScriptType::getSupers, Collections.emptySet());
}
```

But `TypeScriptType::getSupers` doesn't exist and things get complex from there quite quickly. I could implement my own version of that, the original looks like this:

```
public JSClass @NotNull [] getSupers() {
    List<JSClass> superClasses = ContainerUtil.newArrayList(this.getSuperClasses());
    Collections.addAll(superClasses, this.getImplementedInterfaces());
    JSClass[] var10000 = (JSClass[])superClasses.toArray(JSClass.EMPTY_ARRAY);
    if (var10000 == null) {
        $$$reportNull$$$0(10);
    }

    return var10000;
}
```

But then we have to reimplement getSuperClasses... and I'm getting worried that I don't really understand this problem at all. Is there an API to manage these relationships in the Intellij Plugin framework?

If anyone has even some advice on how to approach this problem, I'd be very happy for any input at all.

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this is to move every single Type to its own file and use the plugin's dependency view.